# Filter Facebook News Feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

I have my friends properly organized in lists and I currently only care about news feed from one list and companies that I have liked.

The other lists are just useless for me, it would be pain to hide posts from each in other list, or unfriend everyone else. I am wondering is there a way to filter news feed to just the list I can choose?

I figured out clicking on most recent allows me select the list I care about to show only those feeds, however it doesn't save as default setting, and it revert back to default setting. Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook keeps on performing some sort of A/B testing, where few users (based on some business logic of facebook) will see one UI, while rest will see other UI. 
 I don't know how it could be possible at the time this question was posted, but currently you can give a try to these steps:

1. On sidebar of the homepage, you will see 'triple dot' next to `News Feed` link.
2. Click on this. If you don't have this option, it means right now this feature is not available to you.
3. You will see multiple options here, like: 
   **i. Prioritize who to see first**: Select names of friends whose posts you want to see on the top of your timeline.
   **ii. Unfollow people to hide their post**: You can unfollow your friends right from here, so that their post will never be displayed on your TL, unless you follow them again.
   **iii. Reconnect with people you have unfollowed**: If you had previously unfollowed someone, you can refollow them right from here.
   **iv. Discover Pages that match your interest**: Relevant pages based on your activity will be suggested by facebook. Click like to get their notification.
   **v. See more options**: If you have any hidden apps then you can manage them from here.
   Please have a look at the screenshot:

[image: Facebook timeline filter setting]

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this currently within Facebook UI.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to view a single list of friends. Why not make a bookmark for that friend list, and put it in your browser's bookmarks toolbar for easy access, then whenever you visit Facebook, instead of going to the default facebook page at facebook.com, click your friends list bookmark instead.

BTW if you want the "**Most Recent**" setting to stick permanently, you need to use a browser extension to force it, as Facebook's interface is designed to "forget" your setting preference.

The FB Purity browser extension has an option to force Facebook to stay on the "Most Recent" newsfeed. You can get it here: **http://fbpurity.com**

After installing **FB Purity**, tick the "**News Sort: Most Recent**" option on the FBP options screen, then click the "**Save and Close**" button.